# GLSL 1.2 floor() issues in Vertex Shader

Tags: opengl, glsl

I'm trying to calculate texture coordinates based on the coordinates of an incoming vertex in the Vertex Shader. This is a stripped down version of my attempt:

```
#version 120

varying vec4 color;

uniform sampler2D heightmap;
uniform ivec2 heightmapSize;

void main(void)
{
   vec2 fHeightmapSize = vec2(heightmapSize);
   vec2 pos = gl_Vertex.zx + vec2(0.5f, 0.5f);
   vec2 offset = floor(fHeightmapSize * pos) + vec2(0.5f, 0.5f);

   if (fract(offset.x) > 0.45f && fract(offset.x) < 0.55f 
       && fract(offset.y) > 0.45f && fract(offset.y) < 0.55f)
      color = vec4(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
   else
      color = vec4(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);

   // gl_Position = ...
   // ...
}
```

gl_Vertex is in `[-0.5, 0.5]^2`, on the XZ-plane. So what I am basically trying to do, is to

- first create a float vec2 from the ivec2 heightmapSize, which holds the width and height of the heightmap sampler.
- Then I'm converting the vertex coordinates to the interval `[0, 1]^2`.
- Then I'm calculating the offset in texture coordinates by multiplying the vertex position with the heightmap size. The left part (using `floor()`) should return the number of texels in each direction.

  > Example: The texure is of size `4x4`, position is `(0.55, 0.5)`. This means I would got 2 texels to the right, and two texels upwards -> `(2.0, 2.0)`.

  In the right part, I add another `(0.5, 0.5)` because I want the center of the texel. The `(2.0, 2.0)` becomes `(2.5, 2.5)`. **Note:** whatever the coordinates are, the fractional part should be `0.5` in the end.

Now comes the strange part. I'm testing for the result by specifying two colors. If the fractional part of the offset is "close" to `0.5`, I'm setting the resulting color to green, otherwise red. The image is almost all red.

> [image: Result image]

How is it possible, that either `fract()` does not result in a vector of two integer values (or close to integer because of float accuracy), or the adding of `vec2(0.5, 0.5)` has no effect? Am I missing something else?

Comment: Hmm. I don't see any reason for the behaviour you're seeing. At least as long as `fHeightmapSize` is not so large so that you get floating point precision issues, which I find very unlikely in your situation. Cn you try to directly visualize the fractional parts using color=vec4(fract(offset),0.0,1.0)?

Comment: Thanks, [here](http://i.imgur.com/i4rxzoT.png) is the image with the settings you requested. `heightmapSize` is `(256, 256)` in this scenario.

Comment: There is something seriuosly going wrong here - the blue channel should be zero anywhere. Maybe your fragment shader is messing with these colors. Especially, that yellow patch should have something close to 0.5,0.5,0 if it were consistent whith the previous picture and the brach you has. I don't know what's going on. Maybe we need to see more code. Small side note: you do not need to use the `f` suffix for float constants in GLSL.

Comment: Apologies, there was some broken specular lightning going on. I corrected the image in the question and here is the result with your changes: http://i.imgur.com/bp0hbLn.png

Comment: OK. The images do make slightly more sense than before. I still have no idea of what might be going on... What I find suspicious is that that it seems to work for low values.

Comment: Thanks anyway. I guess as you don't see any issue with the code there must be something else going on. I have to use mesa 9.2.2, so I'm currently checking for fixed bugs in the git change log since version 9.2.2, especially for `floor()` and/or `fract()`.

Comment: By the way, this should be generating a parse error without a `#version` directive. The floating-point `f` suffix is lexically undefined in GLSL 1.10. In a strict GLSL compiler such as Apple's in OS X 10.4, you must have `#version 120` to use `f`.

Comment: Sorry, I added `#version 120` to the shader code. I'm just too used to the `f`, I wrote it without thinking about it. I've currently given up on this issue, I guess it has something to do with bad/old drivers or libraries.